# Missing required parameter for my route name

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-blade

One of the routes configured in the "home" of my page is not working.

My web.php:

```
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class,'index'])->name('home');

Route::get('/post/{red:slug}', [PostRedController::class,'index'])
    ->name('red');

Route::get('/post/{green:slug}', [PostGreenController::class,'index'])
    ->name('green');
```

My HomeController:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home',
    [
        'red' = PostRed::limit(10)->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
        'red_images' = PostRedImage::limit(2)->get();
        'green' = PostGreen::limit(5)->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
        ]);
    }
}
```

My home view

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < $red->count(); $i++)
    <div>
        <a href="{{ route('red', $red->slice($i, 1)->first()?->slug) }}"</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a href="{{ route('green', $green->slice($i, 1)->first()?->slug) }}"</a>
    </div>
@endfor
```

When I have to load the home, it shows the message

```
Missing required parameter for [Route: green] [URI: post/{green}] [Missing parameter: green].
```

The "red" route works.

That way it doesn't give an error, but it doesn't have the link to the post.

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < $red->count(); $i++)
    <div>
        <a href="{{ route('red', $red->slice($i, 1)->first()?->slug) }}"</a>
        <a href="#0"</a>
    </div>
@endfor
```

I want to open GreenPost also using slug.

Comment: for the sake of curiosity.. did you see what the expression `$green->slice($i, 1)->first()?->slug` evaluates to? maybe there are iterations of that loop where that value just isn't there and that's why the routing path can't be built

Comment: also that `PostGreen::limit(5)` is suspicious for the green route compared to the red with `limit(10)`

Comment: I understand your question, but in the same view there is also the code: ```{{ $green->slice($i, 1)->first()?->title }}```. And it works, it just doesn't work on the route.

Comment: I'm not familiar with laravel but in php that looks like the null safe operator.. that won't throw an error when reading the property of a null object. But yet the returned result will be null and maybe such parameter requires a not null value for the parameter

Comment: the point is that you have a for loop tuned with `$i < $red->count()` but the red and green arrays don't have the same length. So that's why you are having the issue. If you connect everything I said so far it makes the entire picture

Comment: You're right, it needed to be the same length. Thank you.